# Fuzzy c-means and using specific cluster values

Tags: matlab, fuzzy, fuzzy-c-means

Say that I want to use specific cluster center values in the [fcm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/fcm.html) function? Can I assign the cluster center values while running the `fcm` function?

Thanks.